# Having trouble drawing chart using data from JSON and Google Charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a line graph using google charts and a JSON that I have created from MYSQL. I have tried to use the examples provided on Google Visualization API but haven't been successful.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {
    var selectedValue = $("select option:selected").val()
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '/social_scores/'+selectedValue,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
             /* Create the charts after operation succeeded */
             var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);
             data.addColumn('string', 'Week');
             data.addColumn('number', 'Overall');
             data.addColumn('number', 'Presence');
             data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
             data.addColumn('number', 'Engagement');
             data.addColumn('number', 'Reputation');
             data.addRows([
                 ['Week 1', response.overall_score, response.presence_score, response.popularity_score, response.engagement_score, response.reputation_score ],
                 ['Week 2', response.overall_score, response.presence_score, response.popularity_score, response.engagement_score, response.reputation_score ]
             ]);
            var options = {
                title:'Key Success Metrics over time across all channels',
                'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
                'width': 620,
                'vAxis': {minValue:"0", maxValue:"100", gridlines:{count: 7} },
                'chartArea': {top:"50", left: "40"},
                'legend':{position: 'top', alignment: 'start' }
           };
           var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_graph'));
           chart.draw(data, options);
          ("select").change(function(){
            alert($("select option:selected").val())

           });


        }
    });
};
```

Here is the graph span that should be update:

```
<span id="line_graph"></span>
```

Here is the drop down html:

```
<select id="social_entity_id" name="social_entity[id]">
<option value="1">DataSimply</option>
<option value="2">mbonat</option>
<option value="3">OpenLabel</option>
<option value="4">scrible</option>
<option value="5">jivesoftware</option>
<option value="6">lithiumTech</option>
<option value="7">getsatisfaction</option>
<option value="8">tumblr</option>
<option value="9">nytimes</option>
<option value="10">gilt</option>
<option value="11">groupon</option>
<option value="12">Bloombergnow</option>
<option value="13">NWSCorp</option>
<option value="14">etsy</option>
<option value="15">foursquare</option>
<option value="16">Yelp</option>
<option value="17">businessinsider</option>
</select>
```

Where should I put the change event so that the numbers changed based on the selected value of the dropdown?

Comment: Is it throwing any error at all? It will be nice if you have this in jsFiddle as well so we can visualize what's going on.

Comment: Can't throw into jsFiddle because of where the data is coming from. Here is the error it is throwing: `Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'jsonData.overall_score' of undefined`

Comment: How does the jsonData looks like? It looks like it doesn't have the overall_score property in it.

Comment: `{"created_at":"2013-01-15T14:04:31Z","engagement_score":0,"favourites_count":0,"follow_count":286,"friends_count":1627,"id":2941,"overall_score":10,"popularity_score":0,"presence_score":286,"reputation_score":200,"retweet_count":0,"score_period_end":"2013-01-11","score_period_start":"2013-01-10","score_period_type":"Week","score_timestamp":"2013-01-15T14:04:31Z","social_entity_id":1,"tweet_count":98,"updated_at":"2013-01-15T14:04:31Z"`

Comment: I think I might know what your issue is. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Please check out my answer and see how that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX operation works asynchronously, so you need to wait until the operation has completed before initializing your charts.

```
$(function() {
    var chart;

    var drawChart = function {
        var selectedValue = $("select#social_entity_id option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '/social_scores/'+selectedValue,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
                 /* Create the charts after operation succeeded */
                 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response);
                 data.addColumn('string', 'Week');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Overall');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Presence');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Engagement');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Reputation');
                 data.addRows([
                     ['1', response.overall_score, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
                     ['1', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]);

                var options = {
                    title:'Key Success Metrics over time across all channels',
                    'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
                    'width': 620,
                    'vAxis': {minValue:"0", maxValue:"100", gridlines:{count: 7} },
                    'chartArea': {top:"50", left: "40"},
                    'legend':{position: 'top', alignment: 'start' }
               };
               chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_graph'));
               chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        });
     }

     google.load("visualization", "1", {'callback': drawChart, packages:["corechart"]});

     $('#social_entity_id').change(drawChart);

});
```

Comment: How can I replot the data on a change event?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? You can just call drawChart() whenever you want to refresh the view. Make sure that to empty out whatever element is used to render the graph before you replot though. I assume this `line_graph` is responsible for that.

Comment: Yeah, the line_graph div holds the graph.

Comment: You can do something like: `$("select").change(function(){drawChart();});`

Comment: Update your post with the HTML so I can see what it looks like.

Comment: Move the $('select').change(...) outside of drawChart() and it should work.

Comment: Still not working. Do you think you can update your solution code?

Comment: Please see my revision and refactoring. Message me if this doesn't work still.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23198/discussion-between-robertwclark-and-dennis-rongo)